# Why momentary chemical smell after Tankless Hot Water Heater install

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, tankless

Why is my hot water stinky for a few seconds? This is a strong but hard to describe chemical smell like CPVC glue, not rotten eggs and not sewage or gas.
I put in a new propane-fired tankless water heater with integral recirculation pump and remote cross-over valve 4 weeks ago on CPVC piping in the garage. After the heater has been idle for a while, the water that has been sitting in it gets a strong chemical smell. You can't smell it at the heater, and it takes a while to pass through the pipes to the fixture (sink/shower) depending on the length of the pipe run. The smell only comes from hot water, so it is not coming from my well water (meaning it is not stinky on the cold side). The smell goes away in a few seconds.

I was thinking it was contamination burning off inside the heat exchanger.  One problem with that notion is I believe there would be far more widespread discussion of this online.

To distinguish between a smell that comes from water that's been sitting in the heat exchangers leeching versus some smell coming from initial heating, I plan to do a test allowing water to sit overnight then disable the heater and run the hot water and see if it still stinks but have not yet done this test.

Note that the burner cannot in my opinion contaminate the water and the smell is IN THE WATER. Pipe dope from supply piping could contaminate the heat exchanger, but I found no residue on the inlet screen whatsoever.

Since I'm on well water, I'll mention that we attempting to manage an acidity problem as well as an iron problem whose calcium filter is hardening the water.

Comment: How is it piped?  It could be fresh pipe dope absorbed into the water when sitting idle.